# Facebook White Screen

Tags: facebook

We keep getting a white-screen on our FB application, although the server is successfully getting hit and no errors are occurring.  Is there a setting or something we can do to resolve this?  Does anyone know about this issue?

Comment: Did you check the source code of the rendered page?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing on the page except for the outer facebook stuff.  Nothing from our application, even though our server says that it rendered the page normally

Answer (score 0):

Browsing to http://m.facebook.com and turning on/off "Login approval" fixed it for me (https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=approvals&view).

Answer (score -3):

Had the same thing and it turned out to be a Secure Browsing feature.  Go to Account Settings, then click on Account Security and click the option for Secure Browsing (https) and all pages will load correctly.